# How to change the percentage contents of a parent().parent() values in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("[name=editMarksAccSubmit1]").live('click',function(){
    $syllabus=$(this).attr("data-syllabus");
    $student=$(this).attr("data-studentId");
    $percentage=$(this).attr("data-percentage");
            $marks=$(this).parent().parent().find("[name=marz]").val();
            $AccMarks=$(this).parent().parent().find("[name=mar]").val();
            alert($marks);
            alert($AccMarks);
            $percentage=$(this).parent().parent().find("[name=marz]").val();
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=academicMarksAction] > span").html($marks);
            var js={"syllabusId":$(this).attr("data-syllabus"),"studentId":$student,"marks":$marks};
            $.post(url+"admin/Edit/insertValues",js,function(data){
            marksAccClose1();
            },"json");
        });
```

I am able to `edit the marks and max-marks`,but my question is how to change the percentage automatically when i submit for that particular parent() div and changes in the Total div which is at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

I think, if i understood your question you just need `$('#element').parents().eq(1).date(percentage, "value");`
or $('#element').parents().eq(1).attr(data-percentage, "value");

Comment: i didn't get u... can u tell according or explain to my code?

Comment: just tell me how to calculate the percentage of the rows i edit and total to be changed... that will be helpful with a js function